# Thunderbird (24.1.1): properly disable accounts

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to **properly** disable a few Thunderbird accounts. The reason is that I have more than a dozen accounts some of which become accessible as various things change daily (network changes, workflow changes). When that happens I would like to simply click somewhere on the account panels to disable/reenable it. Then ideally T. would stop polling and eliminate its entry from the *From:* pulldown during *Compose*.
"Properly" means that I would not have to mess with the configuration every day to disable the account and then have to remember those settings to reenable it.
Even better would be to have Profile-like configurations where I could apply the changes in batches. Last time I looked (a year ago) the Profiles machinery was too clumsy to be able to do this: accounts could not be moved around easily.

EDIT 1: One of my troublesome accounts keeps popping up login password requests. Tried disabling both "check for new messages [...]" boxes with no luck. Deleted 3 drafts messages thinking that even though it is not checking for new messages it might try to contact the server to sync draft messages: no luck. Finally I shut it up by appending "--DISABLED" to the server name.

In sum, my desired Disable Account Feature would:

1. Alert me that the account in question is disabled (currently I cope by prefixing "DISABLED: " to the Account Name).
2. Hide the disabled account from the UI (except of course from a reenable list) while keeping all the settings intact.
3. Quit trying to contact the server or engage in any other activity (currently I uncheck the "check for new messages [...]" checkboxes and append "--DISABLED" to the Server Name).